# How to solve a timeout error in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following set up:

In routes I have:

Route::get('articles', 'ArticlesController@index');

The index method in the controller is simply:

```
public function index()
{
   $articles = Article::all();
   return View('articles.index', compact('articles'));
}
```

and in the view:

```
@extends('../app')
@section('content')
<h1>Articles</h1>
<p>
    @foreach($articles as $article)
    <article>
        <h2><a href="{{action('ArticlesController@show', [$article->id])}}">{{$article->title}}</a></h2>
        <p>{{ $article->body }}</p>
    </article>
    @endforeach
</p>
@stop
```

I attempted to replace the:

```
$articles = Article::all();
```

with

```
$article = Article::latest()->get();
```

such that I can actually show the articles latest first.
I got the error:

```
FatalErrorException in Str.php line 322:
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

and the call stack is:

```
in Str.php line 322
at FatalErrorException->__construct() in HandleExceptions.php line 131
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError() in HandleExceptions.php line 116
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() in HandleExceptions.php line 0
at Str::snake() in helpers.php line 561
at snake_case() in ControllerInspector.php line 105
at ControllerInspector->getVerb() in ControllerInspector.php line 78
at ControllerInspector->getMethodData() in ControllerInspector.php line 39
at ControllerInspector->getRoutable() in Router.php line 251
at Router->controller() in Router.php line 226
at Router->controllers() in Facade.php line 210
at Facade::__callStatic() in routes.php line 21
at Route::controllers() in routes.php line 21
in RouteServiceProvider.php line 40
```

... etc

I have restored the controller method to what it was, but the error persists.

Can you please tell me how I can solve this problem?

Comment: what is `id` here? An index of the article array?

Comment: What happens when you try `$article = Article::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();` instead of `$article = Article::latest()->get();` or whatever time stamp field you have?

Comment: it turned out that my setup was faulty, xamp with laravel needs to have xdebug disabled for some reason

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The **Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded** error is not related to Laravel but rather your PHP configuration.

Here is how you can fix it. The setting you will need to change is `max_execution_time`.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

max_execution_time = 30     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 8M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)
```

You can change the `max_execution_time` to `300` seconds like `max_execution_time = 300`

You can find the path of your PHP configuration file in the output of the `phpinfo` function in the `Loaded Configuration File` section.

Comment: Laravel routes on localhost are very very slow. `Route::get('/', function() {die('here')});` shows 'here' string after 5 seconds. PHP7 + Apache. Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 with the same behavior.

Comment: Updating max_execution_time is not a good solution. try to optimize the query.

Comment: instead of updating the configuration file use `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` in required pages.

Comment: @GeoTom The second argument to ini_set() needs to be a string instead of an integer. `ini_set('max_execution_time', '300');` http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: when updating `max_execution_time` to 300, the error now becomes ->>

> Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

Comment: But why in only certain modules?

Answer (score 61):

it's a pure PHP setting.
The alternative is to increase the execution time limit only for specific php scripts, by inserting on top of that php file, the following:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 180); //3 minutes
```

Comment: where should I add this in Laravel, when inserting this in the controller I get an error `Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script`

Comment: @davejal - I'm sure you have moved on from this issue, but to answer your question, put the call to ini_set, just under the namespace declaration, so it would be on approximately line 5 of the file.

Answer (score 36):

In Laravel:

Add set_time_limit(0) line on top of query.

```
set_time_limit(0);

$users = App\User::all();
```

It helps you in different large queries but you should need to improve query optimise.

Comment: I think you should never do that in production, cause it will do some serious impact to your performance. This code will **execute your code without time limit**. I suggest you to set this timer, e.g. 100 seconds or later. http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: As mentioned setting to 0 is.. questionable at best. Even if you do 100 like the above commenter mentioned, or even 300; Something is better than nothing: `0` here

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes you just need to optimize your code or query, Setting more max_execution_time is not a solution.

It is not suggested to take more than 30 for loading a webpage if a task takes more time need to be a queue.

Comment: sometimes you have no choice

Comment: @ShaneMit you could run your heavy code in background

Comment: @ Alireza Aboutalebi again, sometimes you have no choice.  I have been tossed into legacy systems where I need to have a script run for more than 30 seconds.  It happens sometimes so you can't act above a situation, as sometimes you have no choice.

Comment: @ShaneMit Right

Comment: If your code is heavily reliant on 3rd party API's and then doing a lot of processing you sometimes have no choice as 30 seconds will just no cut it!  Of course optimisation helps and of course we can try and separate out tasks but it simply isn't always possible when you come in to a project as a contractor and you have very tight schedules.  "This needs rewriting," I say, "No time" comes the reply! :-)

Comment: That is a case too, I have a code that takes 20 min to get finish but in most cases, we should not change the max_execution_time

Comment: Whatever that gets the job done fast... The world we live in, Minimum Viable Product is more important than trying to perfect something that might not suit the market needs yet?

Comment: @CodeGuru yes,that can be the case too

Answer (score 10):

set time limit in __construct method or you can set in your index controller also where you want to have large time limit.

```
public function __construct()
{
    set_time_limit(8000000);
}
```

Comment: This will be applied on the whole controller queries, and if you want for specific query it should be increase, how you can do so?

Comment: @SabaoonBedar you can put set_time_limit(8000000); before that query that should work for only that function.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', $time);
$articles = Article::all();
```

where `$time` is in seconds, set it to 0 for no time. make sure to make it 60 back after your function finish

Answer (score 2):

Add above query

ini_set("memory_limit", "10056M");

Answer (score 1):

Execution  is not related to laravel go to the php.ini file 
In php.ini file  set max_execution_time=360 (time may be variable depends on need)
if you want to increase execution of a specific page then write ini_set('max_execution_time',360) at top of page

otherwise in htaccess 

php_value max_execution_time 360

Answer (score 0):

If using PHP7, I would suggest you changing the default value in the public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule php7_module>
   ...
   php_value max_execution_time 300
   ...
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting your Laravel app on Heroku, you can create `custom_php.ini` in the root of your project and simply add `max_execution_time = 60`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem just now. However, this had nothing to do with modifying the `php.ini` file. It was from a for loop. If you are having nested `for` loops, make sure you are using the iterator properly. In my case, I was iterating the outer iterator from my inner iterator.

Answer (score -1):

By default the max execution time set is 30 seconds. I'm facing this issue when I load a page which is quite big with huge data coming from database. Other factors will cause this issue too like big images, lot of javascript files and big icons. I fixed this issue by adding this line in the entrypoint of laravel application `public\index.php`

```php
ini_set('max_execution_time', '60');
```

I did this for my entire laravel application. But in your case, you can do this on certain pages which are causing this problem. Just do write that line on start of php script for particular page

Answer (score -4):

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

#cambiamos el valor para subir archivos
php_value memory_limit 400M
php_value post_max_size 400M
php_value upload_max_filesize 400M
php_value max_execution_time 300 #esta es la linea que necesitas agregar.
```

Answer (score -24):

You need to just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. It will work after that.