# how to download PDF in laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to fetch data from database and pass this data to pdf view and download it.

I tried this code but its not working:

```
<a href="{{url('/download-PDF/'.$eventData->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Download PDF </a>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('download-PDF/{id}', 'PDFController@pdf');
```

**Controller**

```
class PDFController extends Controller
{
public function pdf($id){
    $getEvent=Event::find($id);
    $eventId=$getEvent->id;


    if(isset($eventId)) {

        $eventData = Event::where('id', $eventId)->first();
        $getDays = Day::where('event_id', $eventId)->get();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($getDays); $i++) {
            $dayId = $getDays[$i]->id;
            $schedule[$i] = DaySchedule::where('day_id', $dayId)->get();
        }

    }

    $pdf=PDF::loadView('pdf',['eventData' => $eventData, 'schedule' => $schedule]);

    return $pdf->download('event.pdf');
}
}
```

**Config**

```
'providers' => [
  Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
 ]

 'aliases' => [
 'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
  ]
```

Comment: whats the error you getting?

Comment: it execute for a while and then get this Error `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270316/how-to-solve-a-timeout-error-in-laravel-5

Comment: This is not necessarily a solution to your problem, but if you know that you will be able to execute a binary on the production server, I've found barryvdh/laravel-snappy to be much better (better rendering) than DomPDF.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any exception?

Here is a code I use for generating the pdfs:

**Controller:**

```
public function generateReport(TimetableRequest $request, $id) {
    $reportData = $this->prepareReportData($id, $request->startDate, $request->endDate);
    $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadView('pdf.report', $reportData);
    return $pdf->download('report.pdf');
}
```

**Config**

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
    ],

'aliases' => [
    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    ...
    'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
    ]
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('projects/{id}/report', 'Controller@generateReport');
```