# Maatwebsite import csv Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded error

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am making an application with upload csv file. but I am having an Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded error. How to handle this on Laravel 5.3? I am uploading a file with a minimum of 1000 lines filling up sql columns. Thank you so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve a timeout error in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270316/how-to-solve-a-timeout-error-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 1):

Add `ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);` in your controller.

or set `max_execution_time = 600` in your php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

You can use in controller `set_time_limit(0);` for setting the max execution time or you can set it to 0 if the time limit is infinite.

or you can go to your php.ini file and set the execution time there