# Sending mail with lumen | Timeout

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, lumen

I have required `composer require illuminate/mail`,

`.env` looks fine :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp-mail.outlook.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=******@hotmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Controller :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
....
....
....
$random = str_random(40);
Mail::send('email.verify', ['user' => $applicant_id, 'random'=>$random], function ($m) use ($findUser) {
   $m->to($findUser->user->email)->subject('Account Verification');
});
```

**It always gives me `"message": "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded",`, I tried it with zoho mail also.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve a timeout error in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270316/how-to-solve-a-timeout-error-in-laravel-5)

Comment: @MaraBoc I have other applicants running to on the same local server, Their mail sending have no issue, I am facing timeout issue with lumen.