# When I run Laravel project on online server domPDF function work but localhost this function not work, PDF not generated, Why?

Tags: javascript, laravel, dompdf

it shows me error like this...

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
>   Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

..
I changed maximum execution time but it not works..
**my route is this** :

```
Route::get('download-invoice/{id}','InvoiceController@downloadPDF')->name('d-invoice');
```

**the controller is** :

```
public function downloadPDF($id){        
    $invoice = Student::join('admission_details','admission_details.ad_student','=','students.stu_id')->where('stu_id',$id)->first();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.invoice', compact('invoice'))->setPaper('a4')->setWarnings(false);
    return $pdf->download('Fee-Structure.pdf');  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve a timeout error in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270316/how-to-solve-a-timeout-error-in-laravel-5)

Comment: First of all what package are you using? The describe the local environment setup, linux, windows, homestead...

Comment: barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Answer (score 0):

ini find the maximum_execution_time and increase it.

Secondly, dont forget to restart the web server.