# Laravel pdf issue: failed to open stream: No such file or directory by using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package

Tags: laravel, pdf

I am update composer and use barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package.

the problem is when i click the button it show me error like image below:-

[image]

Is that anyway to change the folder path? or am I missing code to modify path to download the pdf file?

Comment: You can Include .utm. it is file not found

Comment: I think not this problem. Not using any .ufm format extension

Comment: Have you ran command: `php artisan vendor:publish` ??

Comment: ufm is a font file. Make sure all fonts used in cart.placeholder are installed on your system.

Comment: @lun7code: Try to create a `fonts` directory in `storage` directory i.e. `App/storage/fonts....` Also, remember to make it writable.

Comment: Hi @HirenGohel, Yes. it work but now have another issue is 'Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded'

Comment: @lun7code: The Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded error is not related to Laravel but rather your PHP configuration. Please see this: http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: You Can You External Font like "<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i"
    rel="stylesheet">". It Is not Working

Comment: you can check this link for better solution . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795346/how-to-save-dompdf-file-to-storage-and-name-the-file-dynamicly-in-laravel/74942859#74942859

Comment: you can check this link for better solution . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795346/how-to-save-dompdf-file-to-storage-and-name-the-file-dynamicly-in-laravel/74942859#74942859

Comment: you can check this link for better solution . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795346/how-to-save-dompdf-file-to-storage-and-name-the-file-dynamicly-in-laravel/74942859#74942859

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to run this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Then, try to create a `fonts` directory in the `storage` directory.

i.e. `storage/app/fonts`. Also, remember to make it writable.

For maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded, this is not laravel related issue but it's about php configuration issue. Please see this and fix it: http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

You can also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30290770/6000629

Hope this will helps you!

Comment: From Laravel 5.x, the correct path for storage directory is at the root.  In my case, using Laravel 5.7 was not necessary run  vendor:publish command.

Comment: @herohat: Yes, my bed :), the `storage` folder is in root, and the path is `storage/app/`. Thanks for looking in it :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf/personalpdf', compact('user','result'))->setOptions(['defaultFont' => 'sans-serif']);
```

It worked for me, I didn't make any file/folder

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: This directory must exist and be writable by the webserver process.
under the config file thats what it say: therefore you should create the fonts directory inside the storage.

```
    "font_cache" => storage_path('fonts/'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the reference to css external file in your cart.placeOrder.blade