# Laravel 8 development server stops working after 5 minutes

Tags: php, laravel, web

Laravel version 8.0
PHP version 7.4.25

when I run Laravel development server it stops after 300 seconds but the project works fine even after the error.

λ php artisan serve
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Sun Oct 31 15:23:52 2021] PHP 7.4.25 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in F:\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php on line 59

Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError

Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

at F:\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:59
55▕                             : now()->addDays(30)->getTimestamp();
56▕
57▕         $process = $this->startProcess($hasEnvironment);
58▕
➜  59▕         while ($process->isRunning()) {
60▕             if ($hasEnvironment) {
61▕                 clearstatcache(false, $environmentFile);
62▕             }
63▕

Whoops\Exception\ErrorException

Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve a timeout error in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270316/how-to-solve-a-timeout-error-in-laravel-5)

Comment: @NicoHaase my php max_execution_time has been set to 300 seconds already

Comment: You should never use the serve method in your production environement

Comment: @Aless55 but i have set APP_ENV to local in .env file

Comment: If `max_execution_time`  is set to 300 for the CLI version of PHP, it's more than obvious that the process is killed after 300 seconds. Also, `max_execution_time` does not care about `APP_ENV`

Answer (score 0):

Increase maximum execution time in your server php.ini file.